# How to only allow routing to IP range on particular interface?

Tags: networking, route, ufw

I have two interfaces `eth0` (`192.168.10.x`) and `wlan0` (`172.16.30.x`) on my device (Raspberry Pi, Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)).

Both networks have access to the internet, but I want my device to only use the `eth0` for any IP ranges **apart from** the `172.16.30.x` range which should only go via the `wlan0`.

(Why?  I'm trying to segregate messages on IoT WiFi network from my "safe" one - please don't suggest a router solution, that's not possible for other reasons.)

So

```
172.16.30.x      -->  wlan0
everything else  -->  eth0
```

I also want the changes to persist after reboots.

I assumed that I should use the `route` command, but failed in understanding it.

I've tried the following in `ufw` and it blocks all packets (well, I'm testing with `ping`) on the `wlan0` interface.

```
sudo ufw route allow out on wlan0 to 172.16.30.0/24
sudo ufw deny out on wlan0
```

Can someone help please?

**EDIT**

My routing table (`ip route show`) is

```
default via 192.168.10.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.10.50 metric 202
default via 172.16.30.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 172.16.30.103 metric 303
169.254.0.0/16 dev vethd1130f6 scope link src 169.254.204.146 metric 208
172.16.30.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 172.16.30.103 metric 303
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-97b0ae2f260f7 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-17f0570004a4 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.50 metric 202
```

There's a whole lot of additional Docker networks there.

Comment: What is in your routing table, `ip route show`?

Comment: @tater - added in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `172.16.30.0/24` is the subnet for your WiFi network and the gateway is `172.16.30.1`, you could simply remove the default gateway for the interface using e.g.

```
sudo ip route delete default via 172.16.30.1 dev wlan0
```

If the `172.16.30.0/24` is on another subnet, and your WiFi is e.g. `192.168.1.0/24` with GW `192.168.1.1`, you would need to remove the default gateway and add a static route:

```
sudo ip route delete default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
sudo ip route add 172.16.30.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

Do not try to do this by playing with the firewall rules alone: you will end up in situation where the computer still tries to use the route but it simply fails without trying to use the other interface instead.

Comment: That works, but now how do I persist the delete between reboots?  I can't see how to delete routes with `man 5 interfaces` for example.